# non centrally free actions of ameanable groups on the hyperfinite III_1 factor

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, group-cohomology, von-neumann-algebras, subfactors

Let $R$ be a hyperfinite $\mathit{III}_1$ factor, and let $Out(R)$ be its set of automorphisms modulo inner automorphisms. There is a canonical and important homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb R\to Z(Out(R))$ called the modular flow.

Let $G$ be an ameanable group.

Injective homomorphisms $f:G\to Out(R)$ whose image does not intersect the image of $\phi$ have been well-studied. For example: it is by now well known that this subset of $Hom_{inj}(G,Out(R))$, if you mod it out by the conjugation action of $Out(R)$, is the same thing as $H^3(G,U(1))$.

> **How about when $f(G)$ does intersect the image of $\phi$ in a prescribed way?**

To make things more concrete:
Let $G:=\mathit{Heis}_3$ be the integer Heisenberg group of upper triangular matrices with $\mathbb Z$ coefficients, and let $Z\subset \mathit{Heis}_3$ be its center (isomorphic to $\mathbb Z)$. Fix $a\in \mathbb R$.

**What can be said about injective homomorphisms $\mathit{Heis}_3\to Out(R)$ that map $Z\subset \mathit{Heis}_3$ isomorphically onto $\phi(a\mathbb Z)\subset Out(R)$?**